# Is there a Python Event for swapping between object mode and edit mode?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script that is manipulating the text of a text object. I want this script to work when the user swaps between "edit mode" of the text to "object mode".

Is there some event for that?

For now the script works with a button, but I want to avoid that.